# binarySearch to find closest number to target . undefined as return value

Tags: javascript, undefined, binary-search

I am working on a function that is supposed to return the closest lower number to a target from a list of integers. (i.e [1,23,45,67,94,122], target = 96. should return 94). I have gone through my code multiple times trying to "catch the bug" that makes this function return "undefined" and I haven't been able to find out why... When I print out my variable through the process, they all match what I want but my returning value keeps on being Undefined. I am thinking My problem is in the two first conditionals but, I still can't tell why. Any clue?

This is my code:

```
function binarySearch(arr,target){
  var midpoint = Math.floor(arr.length/2);

  if (arr[midpoint] === target){
    return arr[midpoint];
  }
  if (arr.length === 1){
    return arr[0];
  }

  if (arr[midpoint] > target){
    binarySearch(arr.slice(0,midpoint),target);
  }else if (arr[midpoint] < target){
    binarySearch(arr.slice(midpoint),target);
  }
}
```

binarySearch([1,23,45,67,94,122],96);   => expected return value = 94 // getting = Undefined. :/

Comment: because you do not return in your recursion

Comment: Note that the final `if` (after the `else`) is redundant.  You've already checked the `equals` and the `greater than` cases.

Comment: As Disha Umarwani [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48876270/1243641), this calculates something different from the closest value: the highest value no larger than the target.  For instance if you use the above with target `92`, you get the value `67`,  If that's what you want, fine, but if not, you might look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30245398/1243641

Answer (score 2):

So the original algorithm seems wrong, choosing the largest value less than your target, not the one numerically closest to it.

Here's another version somewhat inspired by [a java version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30245398/1243641), but written for ES6 and recursive like the question's code.

```js
function binarySearch(arr, target, lo = 0, hi = arr.length - 1) {
   if (target < arr[lo]) {return arr[0]}
   if (target > arr[hi]) {return arr[hi]}
   
   const mid = Math.floor((hi + lo) / 2);

   return hi - lo < 2 
     ? (target - arr[lo]) < (arr[hi] - target) ? arr[lo] : arr[hi]
     : target < arr[mid]
       ? binarySearch(arr, target, lo, mid)
       : target > arr[mid] 
         ? binarySearch(arr, target, mid, hi)
         : arr[mid]
}

console.log(binarySearch([1, 23, 45, 67, 94, 122], 96))  //=> 94
console.log(binarySearch([1, 23, 45, 67, 94, 122], 47))  //=> 45
console.log(binarySearch([1, 23, 45, 67, 94, 122], 207)) //=> 122
console.log(binarySearch([1, 23, 45, 67, 94, 122], 0))   //=> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add return statements when you perform the recursive call

```
 function binarySearch(arr,target){
  var midpoint = Math.floor(arr.length/2);

  if (arr[midpoint] === target){
    return arr[midpoint];
  }
  if (arr.length === 1){
    return arr[0];
  }

  if (arr[midpoint] > target){
    return binarySearch(arr.slice(0,midpoint),target);
  }else if (arr[midpoint] < target){
    return binarySearch(arr.slice(midpoint),target);
  }
}
```

Comment: right!!! I thought the return values in the two first conditionals were enough for it to work as "global return values" . thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your algorithm will give correct results.
You need to first find the position where the element should be inserted.
Here is the stack overflow link:
[O(log n) algorithm to find best insert position in sorted array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22123489/olog-n-algorithm-to-find-best-insert-position-in-sorted-array)

```
  function binarySearch(arr,target, l, h){
  var midpoint = Math.floor(l+h/2);

  if (arr[midpoint] === target){
    return midpoint;
  }
  if (l === h){
    return l;
  }

  if (arr[midpoint] > target){
    return binarySearch(arr,target, l,midpoint);
  }else if (arr[midpoint] < target){
    return binarySearch(arr, target, midpoint,h);
  }
}
 function binaryclosest(arr, i){
 x= abs(target - arr[i]) 
 y = arr[i+1] - target
 z = target - arr[i-1]
 if(x<y && x<z){
     return arr[i]
 }
 else{
     if(y<z)
        return arr[i+1]
     else
        return arr[i-1]
 }
}
i = binarySearch(arr, target, l, h) 
value = binaryclosest(arr, i)
```

Then, you should subtract the i-1 and i+1 take a mod and then return whichever is lower

Comment: The OP only asked for the closest value, not the insertion point.  Except for the missing `return`s, the original code looks right, although I haven't tested it.

Comment: So, why does the OP assume a[0] to be the closest? He might have missed something while traversing the other end of array.

Comment: I guess it wasn't mentioned, but I assume the list is sorted.  If that's correct, can you show an example where this would fail?  Perhaps I'm confused.

Comment: Oh, wait, you're right.  I am confused.  This finds the largest number no bigger than the target, but not necessarily the closest one.

Comment: I haven't tested my code but the logic remains the same. But, I'm sure my logic is correct.

Comment: The code worked as expected after correcting the missing return values before the recursive call. Thanks for your help!